# What would be an elegant solution to managing and getting data from multiple excel files

Tags: database, excel, pandas, maps, visualization

Ok, so i found that i need to comply data from multiple reports(aprox 700/month). They're all in xls files in one single sheet and their structure is identical(standard header and columns except number of rows). 
 I am currently using a VBA that pastes rows of formulas and copies the values in a master sheet but i find this a fidgety process sometimes. 
I am planning of having the data visualized either on a map(mind you the files do not contain location information) or in charts.

What would be an elegant way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd  # pandas library
import re  # regular expression library for advanced text matching
from os.path import basename  # basename: to strip filename from path

# This can be whatever path you need.  eg 'C:/myfiles/'
# './' is a reference to the current path and assumes all your files
# are located in the same directory you are running your script.
path = './'

# Get all '.xlsx' files in path
# this is just a way to get a list of file names into a list.
# if you have another way to get this done... fantastic.
filenames = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if re.match(r'\.xlsx$', fn)]

# one of my favorite pandas funcitons.  It will push together a bunch of
# dataframes together either vertically, or horizontally if axis=1 is passed
# In this case, I chose horizontally.  So you'd expect a large dataframe
# with top level column indices specifying the name of the file it came from.
df = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_excel(fn) for fn in filenames],
    axis=1,
    keys=[basename(fn).strip('.xlsx') for fn in filenames]
)
```

Keep in mind, you asked a fairly vague question.  What I've provided is guidance on how to go about it.  Your mileage may vary and you may have to do more research on specific elements.  Maybe even ask more questions.

Comment: I am new to this so I would be more curious in some explanations. Thank you.

Comment: will do.  explanations incoming

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

files = glob('path/to/files/*.xlsx')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in files])
df.to_excel('master.xlsx', index=False)
```

`glob` returns a list of all xlsx files

Then we use `pd.read_excel` to create a DataFrame from each of the files in that list and pass them to `pd.concat` which returns a single DataFrame.

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in files])
```

Finally, you can save to a master file

```
df.to_excel('master.xlsx', index=False)
```